# How to change kernel path in grub.conf?

Tags: grub-legacy

In the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file, how would I change the path name of where the kernel boots from if the boot file is located somewhere outside of /boot?

For example, I would want to load the boot kernel from

```
/home/root/kernel
```

How would I specify that?

The grub.conf file looks like this right now

> title CentOS (2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.i686)
>
> kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.i686
> initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.i686.img

I tried `/../home/root/kernel` but it didn't work. Would I have to change the partition?

Answer (score -1):

Ain't gonna work as /home partition is being mounted in init stage. Kernel need to be loaded from /boot as at time of loading kernel no other partition is mounted. Unless you specify root device. For example:

```
menuentry 'Linux 3.10.17 (sde) kernel-3.10.17-g' {
        root=hd0,1
        linux /boot/kernel-3.10.17-g domdadm dolvm root=/dev/md3
        initrd /boot/initrd-3.10.17-g
}

menuentry 'Linux 3.10.17 (sdf) kernel-3.10.17-g' {
        root=hd1,1
        linux /boot/kernel-3.10.17-g domdadm dolvm root=/dev/md3 
        initrd /boot/initrd-3.10.17-g
}
```

Comment: There must be way because it's in my homework...

Comment: This is GRUB 2 syntax. The question clearly asked about GRUB Legacy.